# Excel VBA: How to use RegExp.replace to remove characters from a string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, regex, macros

In VBA Excel I am working with Regular Expressions.
I have enabled Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 and am trying to use RegExp for the following.

```
Input: "234;BB-154"
Expected Output "234;154"
```

Instead Values = "[^\d;]+234;BB-154"

Below is my code.

```
Sub NumbersOnly()
    Dim Values As String
    Dim Value As String
    Set Regex=New RegExp
    Value = "234;BB-154"
    Values = Regex.replace(Value, "[^\d;]+")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to use RegEx is below.

```
Dim Values As String
Dim ValuesRaw As String

Dim regexOne As Object
Set regexOne = New RegExp

regexOne.Pattern = "[^\d;]+"
regexOne.Global = False

ValuesRaw = "234;BB-154"
Values = regexOne.replace(ValuesRaw, "")
```

Comment: Since you have set the reference, seems better to `Dim regexOne as RegExp` instead ot the more generalized `Object`.